# Trying to push an affiliate program onto members, how soon is too soon?

Tags: users, affiliate

On a site I run we have recently launched an affiliate program - one of the groups of people we want to target as potential affiliates are current members of the site - I mean who better to sell a service than the users of the service!

I want to ask how soon is too soon to ask the member if they would like to become an affiliate of ours?

We had been toying with the idea of putting it into the thank you email used when they sign up, but I think that is maybe too soon.

Has anyone had to do anything similar? We want to catch people as soon as possible but don't want to bombard a new user too much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not want to ask them to do it once they've signed up: aside from scaring them away, they don't really know much about the service and therefore will not be very effective at promoting it. I would target the people who have been using your service for a decent amount of time, such as one month, as they will be much more experienced with your service and do a better job promoting it.